# Dual HBA's link status and WWN's

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network

I try to configure a brand new SAN configuration with RHEL 6.6. SAN team requested host wwn's for zoning, which I believe are individual hba's wwn's. Anyhow here is my scenario:

My hba's are dual port. But only one port is in use. So in total I have 3 hba's. and each of them are dual ports. Fiber cables are attached let's say port 0 of each hba.

I can use different tools and commands and find all wwn's. For 3 hba I have 6 wwn in total. But only 3 in use.

So how I can find which wwn is actually attached to SAN?

I also checked link status but all look as "down" (link_state).

Comment: Save yourself some patching grief and just give them all six WWN's

Comment: SAved some time and visited data center. Fortunately there was a label on HBA'ss where wwn's for port 1 and 2 were separately marked. This resolved my problem, but just wanted to know if there were a way to do it w/o visiting DC.  Thanks for comment.